# Sending a PHP variable to another page via click on anchor tag

Tags: php, mysql, post

This is a simplified version of the files that I am working with:

On **product-list.php** I have something like:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="prouduct-detail.php">Product1</a></li>
<li><a href="prouduct-detail.php">Product2</a></li>
<li><a href="prouduct-detail.php">Product3</a></li>
</ul>
```

on **product-detail.php** I want to use something like:

```
include_once("db_config.php");

$product_detail_query = 
          'SELECT *
           FROM prod_details          
           WHERE
           product_name = ???';
```

When someone clicks on a product in product-list.php I want the text between the anchor tags to get sent to product-detail.php and beplaced in the SQL query at product_name = (where I have ???) so I can access that specific row and lay out the details.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Product List.php

```
<a href="product-detail.php?product_id=1">Product</a>
```

On product-detail.php

```
$product_id = (int)$_GET['product_id'];
```

Then, bind $product_id to your DB query.

You can easily replace this with a urlencoded product name, but you really should stick with unique identifiers for this.

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo '<a href="product-detail.php?id=' . $product['id'] . '">' . $product['name'] . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Curtis!  How do I bind $product_id into my db query though?  Can't get the syntax down.  I know it is working because I can echo $product_id on to the detail page and it changes depending on which you click on.

Comment: never mind. needed to use mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['product_name']);